# Splitting a list of numbers from txt file on both spaces and new lines, Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to split a list of numbers that are arranged as such in a text file:

```
1 2

3 4

7 9
```

The closest I can get is:

```
    for line in infile:
                nums = line.split()[0]
                print(nums)
```

But that only returns the first column... what more can I do here to make sure the numbers are separated by both spaces and new lines?

Comment: What exactly do you want to output?

Comment: I want the numbers to be isolated: 1 2 3 4 7 9 etc

Comment: Do you just want to print all the numbers one per line or do you want a flat list of all the numbers in the file, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data.txt:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Code:

```
numbers = []
for line in open("data.txt").readlines():
    numbers.extend([int(n) for n in line.split()])
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want all the numbers as one list, or as a list of lists?

Since split, by default, considers any amount of whitespace as a separator, for one list, just do

```
infile.split()
```

For a list of lists, where each list is a list of numbers on one line, do

```
[x.split() for x in infile.split('\n') if x != '']
```

This splits the file by newlines ('\n'), then takes each line, and, if it isn't empty (x != ''), splits it.

So for example, with a file with your contents named 'test',

```
open('test').read().split()

>>> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '7', '9']

[ int(x) for x in open('test').read().split() ] # convert to integers

>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9]

[ x.split() for x in open('test').read().split('\n') if x != '' ]

>>> [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['7', '9']]
```

And so on...

Comment: I tried the first method, but got back two per each item:
          `with open(fname, "r") as infile:`
                 `for line in infile:`
                     `nums = line.split()`
                     `print(nums)`

: the result came back ['1', '2'] ['3', '4'] ... when I need them separated.

Comment: You are putting it in a for loop per line. I'm suggesting to just run it on the whole file input, as illustrated above.